# How do I rectify this Cartopy issue?

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror, cartopy

I am trying to create a chloropleth map in Cartopy, but I created the following loop in my program:

```
for i, row in map_df.iterrows():
    
    counties = ShapelyFeature(map_df['GEOMETRY'][i],
                             ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                             facecolor=
                               cmap(norm(map_df['FIPS'][i])),
                             )
    ax.add_feature(counties)
```

But when I run the loop, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-3b3f09edbfc2> in <module>
----> 1 for i, row in map_df.iterrows():
      2 
      3     counties = ShapelyFeature(map_df['GEOMETRY'][i],
      4                              ccrs.PlateCarree(),
      5                              facecolor=

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Does anybody know how to rectify this?

Comment: map_df is a string.

Comment: Can it be converted to another data type, or does it need to?

Comment: Based on the name, it seems like you think it is a dataframe, but somewhere you changed it to a string. I recommend you do some print statements to see what it is.